# ¿Cómo crear formas geométricas con datos dentro?

Tags: html, css, svg

Estoy buscando la forma de mostrar un texto de mi base de datos dentro de una forma geométrica un tanto compleja. Necesito que se pueda hacer con `html`, `css` y/o `php`.

Esta es la forma que quiero hacer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la idea es que dentro de cada uno de los espacios de esa imagen vaya un dato

Editado:

Ya revisé el SVG y pude hacer una figura similar pero con círculos, de hecho me parece mejor. Éste es el código

```html
<svg width="600" height="600">
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="150" stroke ='black' fill="transparent"/>
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" stroke ='black' fill="transparent"/>
  <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="50" stroke ='black' fill="white"/>
  <line x1="150" y1="200" x2="50" y2="200" stroke="black"/>
  <line x1="350" y1="200" x2="250" y2="200" stroke="black"/>
  <line x1="200" y1="50" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="black"/>
  <line x1="200" y1="300" x2="200" y2="350" stroke="black"/>
  <rect x="175" y="185" width="50" height="30" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Ahora quisiera poner por ejemplo el contenido de una variable en el rectángulo rojo. ¿Cómo podría hacer eso?

Comment: cesar, puedes agregar como estas dibujando la figura?

Comment: Hola sioesi, no no la he dibujado aún porque no se como hacer ese tipo de figura, además quisiera saber que metodo emplear para hacer las 2 cosas

Comment: lamentablemente en este foro jamas te van a dar una respuesta si tu no intentas algo, aqui se ayuda a resolver errores, no a hacer codigos porque si, te invito a investigar, probar, fallar y volver al foro!

Comment: La pregunta dejó de ser demasiado amplia en cuanto OP añadió el código de lo que llevaba en SVG

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando SVG es muy simple, sólo que tendrás que cambiar algunas de las cosas que estás usando:

- En lugar de `circle` debes usar `rect` para dibujar rectángulos/cuadrados, y ponerle los atributos `rx` y `ry` para redondear los bordes (funcionarán como un `border-radius`).
- El orden importa: debes ver qué elementos están por encima de qué otros y reordenar siguiendo esa lógica.
- Para simplificarte la vida y evitar tener que hacer cálculos, usa un `clip-path` que corte las líneas y las limite a la caja contenedora.
- Para simplificar el código, como muchos elementos van a tener las mismas propiedades, englóbalos en un `g` que tenga esas popiedades y se heredarán.
- Para centrar el texto, he seguido lo que explico en esta [otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/38781/250) ([original del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31522006/3695983)).

Y el código quedaría así:

```html
<svg width="600" height="600" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="600" rx="120" ry="120" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="transparent" clip-path="url(#myClip)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="600" height="600" rx="120" ry="120" />
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="600" y2="600" />
    <line x1="600" y1="0" x2="0" y2="600" />
    <rect x="60" y="60" width="480" height="480" rx="100" ry="100" fill="white" />
    <line x1="300" y1="0" x2="300" y2="600" />
    <circle cx="300" cy="300" r="180" fill="white" />
    <line x1="0" y1="300" x2="600" y2="300" />
    <rect x="200" y="200" width="200" height="200" rx="40" ry="40" fill="white" />
    <text x="50%" y="50%" alignment-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:40px">VALOR</text>    
  </g>
</svg>
```

Entonces ahora lo único que te hace falta es con JS o PHP cambiar el valor que se muestra en el centro y ya está.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias
Justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: Genial. Si quieres te puedo poner una versión en CSS que hice cuando no sabía si lo que querías era PHP, HTML o CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Sé que al final lo pusiste con SVG (que personalmente prefiero), pero antes de que editaras la pregunta, cree una pequeña versión en HTML+CSS de lo que buscabas. Te lo pongo como alternativa, aunque realmente la opción de SVG es mejor y tiene la ventaja de que escala bien.

La idea sería usar `div` para hacer los rectángulos y círculos, y los pseudo-elementos `::before` y `::after` para dibujar las líneas. El código sería así:

```css
.dato, .dato div {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  background:white;
  z-index:2;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.dato div {
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:20px;
}

.dato {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.dato::before,.dato::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:-50px;
  left:100px;
  width:0px;
  height:300px;
  border-right:1px solid black;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
}

.dato::after {
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
}

.dato .cuadrado {
  width:160px;
  height:160px;
}

.dato .circulo {
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  border-radius:100%;
}

.dato .circulo::before, .dato .circulo::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  border-left:1px solid black;
  width:0px;
  height:200px;
  top:-40px;
  left:50%;
}

.dato .circulo::after {
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}

.dato .valor {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dato">
  <div class="cuadrado">
    <div class="circulo">
      <div class="valor">
        VALOR
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```