# ¿Cómo centrar texto dentro de un rectángulo en SVG?

Tags: html, svg

Si tengo el siguiente rectángulo en SVG:

```html
<svg width="500" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 200">
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="1px" fill="white">
    <rect x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="200px" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Y le quiero añadir texto con la etiqueta `<text>`, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que ese texto acabe perfectamente centrado en el rectángulo? Tanto vertical como horizontalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución fácil para centrar texto horizontal y verticalmente en SVG::

1. Haz que el texto esté posicionado en el *centro absoluto* del elemento en el que quieres que aparezca centrado:

   - Si es el padre, puedes poner algo como `x="50%" y ="50%"`.
   - Si es otro elemento, `x` sería el `x` del elemento + la mitad de su ancho y lo mismo para `y` pero con la altura en lugar del ancho).
2. Usa la propiedad [`text-anchor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextAnchorProperty) para centrar el texto horizontalmente con el valor `middle` (traducción mía):

   > **middle**
   >
   > Las caracteres renderizados son alineados de manera que el centro geométrico del texto renderizado estará en el valor inicial de la posición del texto.
3. Usa la propiedad [`alignment-baseline`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#AlignmentBaselineProperty) para centrar el texto verticalmente con el valor `middle` (o dependiendo de cómo quieres que se vea, puede que quieras usar `central` en su lugar).

Aquí dejo un ejemplo de cómo se ve:

```html
<svg width="500" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 200">
  <g stroke="black" stroke-width="1px" fill="white">
    <rect x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="200px" />
    <text x="50%" y="50%" alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="black" stroke="none">TEXTO</text>    
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Nota: ésta es una traducción de [mi propia respuesta en StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31522006/3695983), para poder enlazarla en [otra pregunta relacionada](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38751/250).

Comment: no entiendo, formulas una pregunta hoy, y te auto-respondes con una respuesta tuya de hace 2 años atras?

Comment: @sioesi simplemente he hecho una traducción de otra respuesta propia, porque en [esta otra pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/38751/250) le indicaba a OP que debía centrar el texto y enlazaba al sitio en inglés. Pensé que sería mejor enlazar a una referencia en español en lugar de inglés.

Comment: entiendo! saludos!

Comment: Según la **W3C** lo correcto sería usar [dominant-baseline](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#DominantBaselineProperty)

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Gracias por el comentario, voy a ver cómo sería con `dominant-baseline` y actualizo la respuesta